# OSX container sharing host network with IP from router (DHCP)

Tags: network, docker

I have a production environment, which has 4 hosts. Two hosts are edge processors, the other two are backend processors. All 4 hosts will communicate with additional backend processors. I'd like to, for dev purposes, replicate this as 4 containers running on my Mac (OSX), where all 4 have their own IP address (DHCP from the router) which are visible to the host or any other device connected to the local network (e.g., my iPhone). All 4 are running rocky Linux. I'm not constrained to docker, rancher, etc.

So far, I've tried a variety of technologies (i.e. Docker, Rancher, etc.) with different network configurations. Still, all seem to end up with an isolated network where, at best, the 4 containers can communicate with each other, but another networked device (iPhone) can't see them. I can't (or don't think I can) use port forwarding.

Is what I want to do even possible on osx? I know that docker has restrictions and that `--network=host` doesn't work as expected. Is the same true for Rancher desktop, as well as other technologies built on top of containerd?

Comment: Why not just run four VM's?  Pick your hypervisor... Fusion, Parallels, VirtualBox (shudder).  Is this an Intel or AppleSilicon Mac?

Comment: The container has a variety of libraries, runtimes, and apps which are built up. I use the same container image for CICD as well as local deployment. That's why I picked docker. Some on my team have intel macs others are newer M-series.

Comment: I don’t believe this to be a macOS issue but rather a Docker one.  I’ve run multiple bridged adapters in VirtualBox, Parallels, and QEMU, all with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: agreed, its likely a docker issue. I'm not wedded to docker. However, I would prefer to use a container technology which I can build up and share with CICD pipelines.